# ¿Cómo puedo validar que no se repita el siguiente ciclo for each?

Tags: android, android-studio

Quisiera saber como puedo validar que no se repita la información que contiene el ciclo for, intenté anidar un if pero al final me mostraba el mensaje del crouton las veces que se insertaban los registros, este es el código

```
 DaoEmpresas myDao = new DaoEmpresas(getApplicationContext());

        for (ItemEmpresas empresas : itemEmpresases) {
            if (myDao.insertEmpresa(empresas) == true){

                reload();
            }else{
                Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
            }
        }
```

Sin presionar "Actualizar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Presionando "Actualizar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero evitar es que el ciclo vuelva a repetir los datos, que en vez de que los repita entre en el "else" y lance el crouton con el mensaje de "Sin novedades"

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que deseas, te refieres a que no trate de insertar "empresas" ? En tu programa si inserta llama reload() de otra forma crea un Crouton..... que no deseas realizar?

Comment: lo que pasa es que cuando vuelvo a ejecutar por ejemplo tengo un menú contextual que ejecuta todo el método asíncrono y si lo vuelvo a presionar vuelve a insertar toda la lista de datos

Comment: Voy a poner unas imágenes para que sea mas fácil de entender mi duda

Comment: muchas gracias Alexis, que hace el método : myDao.insertEmpresa() ?

Comment: Ese método es el que hace la inserción de los datos que vienen desde el web service y que se insertan en un la base sqlite

Comment: en ese caso debes asegurar que el método regrese : true si ya se insertaron los datos

Comment: Pero por ejemplo si la inserción se hace, y vuelvo presionar actualizar se volverán a insertar los datos?

Comment: Es que mi idea va más a preguntar si en ese ciclo puedo hacer una validación para que no se repita, solo si por ejemplo hay un nuevo registro que la lista se actualice y se inserte